# What is the most compatible ubuntu version with nvidia gpus?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I understand the question is a little bit weird but I need your help.

What is the most compatible ubuntu version with nvidia gpus?

cheers

Comment: It depends. What is your GPU model?

Comment: Nvidia RTX 30 series

Answer (score 1):

Any supported Ubuntu version with [Nvidia 460](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=nvidia+460&searchon=sourcenames) driver would be good.

But for longer support time the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS would be the most compatible release.
Flavor selection may vary, but I would recommend the [Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) as it integrates well MATE Optimus [applet](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=mate%20optimus) for laptops.